# background attachment:scroll does not render properly on zoom out

Tags: html, css

[image: after reducing zoom percentage][image: before zoom] two images on 25% zoom and 100% zoom. I'm trying to achieve something like this

[required model](http://www.flipkart.com/motorola/motog?otracker=ts_motorola_explore_motog)

Problems I'm facing are first thing is i have a header in which it has navigation bar which has four things home,about,.. .when i reduce the zoom percentage to 25%.The navigation bar items are going out of the div.it.

Second thing is when i reduce the zoom percentage,image is not rendering properly.it is decreasing in size.

Third problem I'm facing is that the header-cont(div) and the center-cont(div) are merging.i know that this is something related to margin collapsing but I'm unable to solve .
            I'm beginner please help me.

[jsfiddle of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/saimadanmohan/zC94v/)

example:

```
    <div id="page">
<div id="header-cont">
          <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.html" ><img src="bingo.png" /></a> 
             </div>
            <ul id="navigation">
                    <li bgcolor="green">
                        Home                
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        About
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Insurance
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       Contact Us
                    </li>

            </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

<div id="center-cont">
        <div id="center">
                <div id="content">
                 <h3>Travel Insurance</h3>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div id="footer-cont">
        <div id="footer">

        </div>

</div>

<div id="end-cont">
        <div id="end">

        </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body
{
    margin:0 auto;
}

#page
{
    height:2400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
}
#header-cont
{
    position:fixed;
    width:inherit;
    z-index:1;
    padding-top:1px;
}
#header
{   
    position:relative;
    background-color:black;
    height:80px;
    background-image:url(header.png) repeat-x;
}
#logo
{
    position:relative;  
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-left:100px;
    float:left;
}
#navigation
{
    margin-left:150px;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    color:white;    
}
#navigation li
{
    position:relative;  
    float:left;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin:12px 30px
}
#center-cont
{
    position:relative;
    //padding:1px;
    //margin-top:20px;
    width:1000px;   
    //margin:0 auto;
}
#center
{
    height:800px;
    background-image:url(travel.png);
//  background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
//  background-size:cover;
    min-height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
#content
{
    z-index:10;
    color:blue;
}
#footer-cont
{
    //position:fixed;
    width:1000px;   
    top:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#footer
{
    background-color:green;
    height:100px;
    //background-attachment:fixed;
}
      #end-cont
      {
    width:1000px;   
     // top:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
      }
        #end
      {
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-image:url(health.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:800px;
      }
```

I'm extremely sorry for my poor indentation.

Answer (score 0):

just a few questions. Are you zooming with the browser? and if so why?
If its a case of accessibility, its much better practice to have a toggle option to increase the size of certain elements.
You will always have issues when zooming with the browser as its to do with the way the browser works with fractions and rounding of element sizes.
Either leave room for expansion or examine why you need the site to work with the browsers Zoom function.

Comment: actually i saw few websites in which the items items positioning remain consistent even after various levels of zoom.and i have seen few articles saying that responsiveness and alignment of the items in page should be independent of the browser. i'm zooming with browser

Comment: ahh yes but there is a difference with responsive web elements and zooming with your browser. You see responsive elements work with widths and sizes of the device and adapting to the correct size to make it fit. There is no "zooming" involved. See [link](www.burkertselect.co.uk). I would recommend reading up on responsive web a bit more as i think you may have the wrong end of the stick here. Zooming and responsive are miles apart.

Comment: Its normal behaviour. I would ask who is using the browser to zoom as its not normally something that is done.
You are essentially asking if its possible to fundamentally re-write the browser and how it reacts and treats fractions. 
Like it said before the best thing to do is leave room for movement. There might be a trick with the text but i haven't come accross it yet and i have been doing it 7 years.

Comment: If you would like i can write you up and send you a much more detailed explanation as to why it doesn't work. I can send it over to you later

Comment: thanks a lot if you can do that thing for me i will be waiting

Comment: Ok i have made up a quick blog and made a few notes on the matter. Let me know if its not clear enough. http://jay-web.co.uk/myblog/?p=4 some up votes would be nice too.